# OnClick Functions Only Work On Second Click

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that creates a few functions: `hidePara1()`, which toggles between the CSS `hidden` attribute of a paragraph; and `displayFrame()`, which does the same with the `display` attribute of an Iframe. Both the paragraph and the Iframe are set to `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` respectively, using CSS.

```
var Par1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var Frame1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");        

function hidePara1() {
  Par1.style.display = ((Par1.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block')
}

function displayFrame() {
  Frame1.style.visibility = ((Frame1.style.visibility!='hidden') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
}
```

And the HTML where the elements exist, and in which I also call the functions via onClick attributes.

```
<a href="#" onClick="displayFrame();">Display iFrame</a>        
<div class="frame-container"><iframe id="iframe1" src="somelink" width="800" height="460"></iframe></div>

<img id="img1" onClick="hidePara1();" src="someimage.jpg">
<div id="para1">
<p>This is the text for paragraph 1.</p>
</div>
```

The problem is bizarre: both onclick events work perfectly, *from the second click onwards*. In other words, neither works when first clicked. This seems to be quite a common problem, judging by the tons of other similar questions I came across, but I can't figure it out, and one of those questions could help me. Note that it also needs to be vanilla JS - frameworks won't do.

A solution to this would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: post your code in a jsfiddle and share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the handler, you access `Par1.style`. The `style` property of an element refers to the style properties in an inline `style="..."` HTML attribute. You specified that elsewhere, you had something like the following in CSS:

```
#para1 {
    display: none;
}
```

This doesn't get picked up in `Par1.style.display`. Look into [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) if you want to see what's currently applied. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9pnm3w2/)

Or just do your conditional the other way around:

```
Par1.style.display = ((Par1.style.display!='block') ? 'block' : 'none')
```

Comment: So the style property doesn't actually get CSS set in a stylesheet? Wow, I'd always thought that was kinda the point of it. 

Anyway, thanks a lot - yours was the answer I understood the best. I decided to switch around the order of the conditional values, and it works perfectly. Out of interest, is there a method or something similar to get the CSS set in a stylesheet? It seems to me not being able to read values from a stylesheet makes style quite redundant. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: other than `getComputedStyle`? you can see the actual CSS rules if you look into the `.sheet.cssRules` of the `<style>` element

Comment: Ah, never mind, I'd misunderstood. I assumed getComputedStyle was a console/debug-specific property rather than a native JavaScript one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you say that these elements are styled using CSS, I assume you mean "styled using some selector, e.g. `#para1 { display:none; }`".

`Par1.style.display` however, only looks for the `style` attribute on your div, which - in the case assumed above - is initially not set. Therefore, the first click will set `style="display:none;"` on the div, which you should be able to observe using developer tools or firebug.

Answer (score 0):

these:

```
var Par1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var Frame1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");
```

shoud be done on load, i.e.:

```
// Global declaration, thos I don't think this matter as much as....
var Par1 ;
var Frame1 ;        


// ...this.  Your calls to getElementById() may be executing before 
// the page has finished loading.  Making the assignment in OnLoad
// guarantees the elements are available an I'm thinking should fix 
// the issue with it not working first time through.

function init() {
  Par1 = document.getElementById("para1");
  Frame1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");        
}
```

html:

```
<body onload="init();">
```

Comment: Is this another way of solving the problem? If not, what's the reason for declaring the variables on load? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2qqwvae0/1/)

Your code works perfectly on the fiddle.

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayFrame();">Display iFrame</a>        
<div class="frame-container"><iframe id="iframe1" src="somelink" width="800" height="460"></iframe></div>

<img id="img1" onclick="hidePara1();" src="someimage.jpg">
<div id="para1">
<p>This is the text for paragraph 1.</p>
</div>

<script>
var Par1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var Frame1 = document.getElementById("iframe1");        

function hidePara1() {
  Par1.style.display = ((Par1.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block')
}

function displayFrame() {
  Frame1.style.visibility = ((Frame1.style.visibility!='hidden') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
}
</script>
```

Comment: It would do - I neglected to include the CSS in my post, and other answerers have made it clear that the CSS was part of the problem. Thanks anyway.